# How can I make this Android044 = g.Count(i => i.Android044 == 1) return a null if the count is equal to 0?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ Query:

```
.Select(g => new AppVersionModel
    {
       DateYYMMDD = g.Key,
       Android044 = g.Count(i => i.Android044 == 1)
    })
.ToList());
```

Android044 is defined as an int?

Right now it counts the numbers in the Android044 but when there are no rows it returns a 0.  Is there a way that I can make it instead return a null.

Is there a way to do this, I can even use another .Select if that could work but I am not very familiar with LINQ so hope there's another solution.

Comment: Android044 =  (g.Count() == 0) ? null :g.Count()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Select(g => new AppVersionModel
{
   DateYYMMDD = g.Key,
   Android044 = g.Count(i => i.Android044 == 1) == 0 
      ? (int?) null 
      : (int?) g.Count(i => i.Android044 == 1) 
})
.ToList());
```

Comment: This iterates over the collection twice though, when the count is not zero: `g.Count()`